# iphone doesn't want read the specific css?

Tags: iphone, css

I read a lot of articles about how build a web site for iphone, all people have more and less the same technique for optimization a website for iphone.

I follow the suggestions, I use the difference css file (iphone.css - i just need the optimization for iphone not all phone) and I tried with a IE conditional and without. I tried also a inline css, inside a common style.css. And finally i also add a meta tag with scalation...but nothing! The iPhone doesn't want read my rules.

I don't have a iPhone i use iPhoney program (I also tried something else but they aren't very good) and sometimes I check form friends iPhone.

My problem is that my main menu that is long like all the page break and going down over the content. Just this. I just need to tell that the screen is more little (min-width-divide) but it doesn't work! And the css doesn't work (i tried to put `#menu: display:none` and the menu was still there). But the directory is right because if i see the site form my laptop i can see the css and can go inside!

The web site is built in wp, i don't know if it's important but it's so simple web site.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you target the iPhone with something like this:

```
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)"
 href="mobile.css">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Yes i have this line of code! And i also tried without a IE conditional.... but nothing change! How is possible?

Comment: This is taken directly from one of my websites that is working 100% with mobile devices. You mentioned that you are not using the iOS MobileSafari. What browser are you testing this with?

Comment: Ok i'm very bad with a mobile so i don't want say stupid think but i'm sure that i saw in Safari (in the iphone). so MobileSafari, when i told that i didn't use it?

Comment: <!--[if !IE]>-->
<link media="only screen and (max-width: 480px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wp-content/themes/nikiscake/iphone.css" />
<!--<![endif]-->